# Adding new row resets added column calculations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im reading in csv files containing data and putting into a pandas dataframe. I want to read 1 set of csv data, then later read other sets of data. Then insert this new data at the top and only do calculations on that row, index 0. Leaving rest of the rows intact and data not touched.

So far i am able to add the row, and do the calculations on the new row. But the old calculated data is gone (calc_1,calc_2,calc_3). From my code below, can you tell me what i am missing?

Thank you

Data looks like this in the csv

```
Date, Time, Open, High, Low
2021/2/25, 08:20:00.0, 160.21875, 160.21875, 160.09375
```

Current output

```
        Date        Open        High         Low     calc_1     calc_2  calc_3
0  2021/2/25  1784.30000  1784.30000  1782.10000     1781.1     1785.3     2.2
1  2021/2/25   160.21875   160.21875   160.09375  159 29/32  160 13/32  0 4/32
        Date        Open        High         Low calc_1 calc_2 calc_3
0  2021/2/25    63.11000    63.20000    63.09000  62.09   64.2   0.11
1  2021/2/25  1784.30000  1784.30000  1782.10000    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  2021/2/25   160.21875   160.21875   160.09375    NaN    NaN    NaN
        Date        Open        High         Low calc_1 calc_2 calc_3
0  2021/2/25    63.11000    63.20000    63.09000  62.09   64.2   0.11
1  2021/2/25    63.11000    63.20000    63.09000    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  2021/2/25  1784.30000  1784.30000  1782.10000    NaN    NaN    NaN
3  2021/2/25   160.21875   160.21875   160.09375    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Expected output  NaN has values from the first block of read data.

```
        Date        Open        High         Low     calc_1     calc_2  calc_3
0  2021/2/25  1784.30000  1784.30000  1782.10000     1781.1     1785.3     2.2
1  2021/2/25   160.21875   160.21875   160.09375  159 29/32  160 13/32  0 4/32

        Date        Open        High         Low calc_1      calc_2     calc_3
0  2021/2/25    63.11000    63.20000    63.09000  62.09      64.2       0.11
1  2021/2/25  1784.30000  1784.30000  1782.10000  1781.1     1785.3     2.2
2  2021/2/25   160.21875   160.21875   160.09375  159 29/32  160 13/32  0 4/32

        Date        Open        High         Low calc_1      calc_2     calc_3
0  2021/2/25    63.11000    63.20000    63.09000  62.09      64.2       0.11
1  2021/2/25    63.11000    63.20000    63.09000  62.09      64.2       0.11
2  2021/2/25  1784.30000  1784.30000  1782.10000  1781.1     1785.3     2.2
3  2021/2/25   160.21875   160.21875   160.09375  159 29/32  160 13/32  0 4/32
```

My Code

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from datetime import date
import datetime
import numpy as np

list_of_dataframes = []

def to_fraction(decimal, denominator):
  
  multiplier = 1 / denominator
  numerator = 0
  
  while decimal > numerator*multiplier:
    numerator += 1
    
  return str(numerator) + "/" + str(denominator)




def stfunc(var,var2):
    fileCount = 0
    global list_of_dataframes
    
    #read csv files.
    for filename in var2:        
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=["Date","Open","Low","High"])
        fileCount = fileCount + 1
        list_of_dataframes.insert(0,df.tail(1))  # use last value in csv only.  
    merged_df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes,ignore_index=True) 
    
    #add 3 columns for calculations
    if var == 'A': 
        merged_df.insert(4,"calc_1",'0',True)
        merged_df.insert(5,"calc_2",'0',True)
        merged_df.insert(6,"calc_3",'0',True)
    merged_df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    
    calc_values = np.array(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"],dtype=float)  
    
    #calculate only new rows added
    for index in range(0,fileCount):
        print(range(0,fileCount))
        merged_df.loc[index,'calc_1'] = "{:.2f}".format(merged_df.loc[index,'Low'] - calc_values[index])
        merged_df.loc[index,'calc_2'] = "{:.2f}".format(merged_df.loc[index,'High'] + calc_values[index])
        merged_df.loc[index,'calc_3'] = "{:.2f}".format(merged_df.loc[index,'High'] - merged_df.loc[index,'Low'])
        
    
    #seperate calculations, only on first call.
    if var == 'A':
        merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'calc_1'] = str(int(merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'Low']-.1875)) + ' ' + to_fraction((merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'Low']-.1875-int(merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'Low']-.1875)),32)
        merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'calc_2'] = str(int(merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'High']+.1875)) + ' ' + to_fraction((merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'High']+.1875-int(merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'High']+.1875)),32)
        merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'calc_3'] = str(int(merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'High']-merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'Low'])) + ' ' + to_fraction((merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'High']-merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'Low']-int(merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'High']-merged_df.loc[merged_df.index[-1],'Low'])),32)

    print(merged_df)

csv_file_list_2 = ['data3.csv']
csv_file_list_1 = ['data1.csv','data2.csv']
stfunc("A",csv_file_list_1)
stfunc("B",csv_file_list_2)
stfunc("B",csv_file_list_2)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about the expect output. What are you hoping to see?

Comment: I've added a expected output section.  the NaN should show the values.